# Laravel - Why am I blocked after visit a given page?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having a very wierd problem using Laravel. I have a site, that is already on a production server. I recently had to make some changes on the project, and what I did was basically set 3 guards:

If I visit **mysiteurl/**, I do a login using the **default guard**.

If a visit **mysiteurl/admin**, I get access to login and use **admin guard**.

If I visit **mysiteurl/b**, I do I login using **b guard**.

On my local environment, everything is working fine. So, I tried to update my production site. Using FTP, I mannually upload file by file, keeping a backup of each one. After that, I did run **php artisan config:cache**, because I was getting a problem saying that b guard didn't exist.

Now comes the problem. When I login using **/admin** and I visit a given page, (let's call it "**admin/courses**") the browser just can't connect to the page. It takes too much time, and the error ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT appears. But everything is there. The route, the controller, the view, database, etc..

The weird thing is that now I'm blocked, I can't connect to the site using my network. If a use my 4g connection on my phone, I am able to visit the site. And if I login as admin and go to the same **courses** page using my 4g connection, I get blocked using it too. I can't even go to the root url to login using another type of guard.

There's no error on the log file from today. No big process running on the serve. The courses page doesn't do anything big, it only lists courses from the databases and all the tables envolved are empty.

I have no clue of what's happening and since my network connection keeps getting blocked by the server, it's very complicated to catch the problem. Can someone give me a help?

Comment: Who or what is blocking you? What do you have set up that could block you?

Comment: I have no idea. I only know when my network connection gets blocked. It's after visiting that courses page. The thing is that I just have access to the FTP connection and I upload the files. The responsible for the server is someone else.

Comment: You'll have to contact them to find out why you're being blocked. With this information, it's hard to tell what's going on. It could be anywhere from too many requests to too many resources, or something else entirely.

Comment: Maybe not your case, but `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` and `guard` issues is most of the time related to a redirection loop. Like _You need to be admin to access this page -> redirect to login: you are authenticated -> redirect back : you need to be admin to access this page -> .... and so on_

Comment: Also, some libraries use the cache; `php artisan cache:clear` I'm not sure `config:cache` will help you in this case. I think it's scoped to the config only.

Comment: It's weird beause if I get the loop problem, I would get it locally too. The site works just fine on my local environment. I will ask the server administrator to run this artisan cache command.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to make this a comment rather than an answer but I can't comment at this point.
First, did you add any more dependencies through composer on your local machine? If so, you will need to run composer install again on the production site so that those dependencies will be added. Same if you added anything with NPM, you will need to run NPM install again.

Comment: I have no new dependencies for composer or new npm packages. I only created a few models, views, controllers, changed the config/auth.php to add 2 new guards, changed the routes/web.php and made a new Mailable class. And that's it.

Comment: Ok. Was a thought. As I said, I would have preferred to just comment but couldn't.. At this point I would try running php artisan cache:clear and see if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that somehow I was having a problem with routes and httaccess. One thing that seems to correct the problem was upload all the files again to a new server and follow this [tutorial](https://divpusher.com/blog/how-to-upload-laravel-to-shared-hosting/).

Now everything is working. Thanks!